# How do I fix the entry.get() function in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

This is a very dumb project to test my absolute beginner skills in python 3.8. But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I don't know what's wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('File Writer')

def getfile():
    text1 = entry1.get()
    text2 = entry2.get()
    text3 = entry3.get()
    text4 = entry4.get()
    fl = fl.get
    save = open('C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\' + fl + '.txt', 'w')
    save.write('Your name: ' +  text1 + '\n')
    save.write('Your Birthdate: ' + text2 + '\n')
    save.write('Your City: ' + text3 + '\n')
    save.write('Your Work: ' + text4 + '\n')
    save.close()


tk.Label(window, text='Welcome to file writer', font="Times 22 bold").pack()
tk.Label(window, text="What is your full name?").pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry(window).pack()
tk.Label(window, text="When is your birthdate (DD/MM/YYYY").pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry(window).pack()
tk.Label(window, text="Where do you live? (City, State, Country").pack()
entry3 = tk.Entry(window).pack()
tk.Label(window, text="What is your job? (position/company)").pack()
entry4 = tk.Entry(window).pack()
tk.Label(window, text='What do you want to name your file').pack()
entry5 = tk.Entry(window).pack()
tk.Button(window, text="Click to save your file", font='Arial 20', command=getfile).pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `entry1`, etc. are not Entries - they're `None`, the result of calling `.pack()` on your Entries.

Comment: Also, `f1` is undefined.

Comment: As a note, you need to add ```.get()```. You forgot parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined the entry, you put the .pack() method, but *pack, grid or place* don't return the element (tk.Entry), but None, so you when you defined the element with the .pack() in the end,

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(window).pack() # .pack() -> returns None
```

the value of the variable entry1 was set to None

To solve that you can define the variable first and then add the pack

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(window) # now the element is stored in the variable
entry1.pack()
```

and I suggest you change the path `C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\`

to an input from the user just so it can be available for other computers
or do something like this

```
import getpass
path = f'C:\\Users\\{getpass.getuser()}\\Desktop\\'
```